# ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint problem in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was creating a database by creating 3 tables (`classes, lectures, taking`), and then altering the table in order add the `foreign key`.

However, I keep getting the following error:
`ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint`

I don't seem to find any problem with the codes so what could be the problem??
(I was using mySQL Workbench. I tried copying and pasting as a txt file because I though it might be a collation problem, but still the same problem would occur)

**The code is as follows:**

```
CREATE TABLE classes (
    course_id VARCHAR(8),
    classes_id VARCHAR(10),
    semester VARCHAR(10),
    year VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (course_id, classes_id, semester, year)
);

CREATE TABLE taking (
    student_id VARCHAR(8),
    course_id VARCHAR(10),
    classes_id VARCHAR(10),
    semester VARCHAR(10),
    year VARCHAR(10),
    grade char(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_id, semester, year)
);

CREATE TABLE lectures (
    professor_id VARCHAR(8),
    course_id VARCHAR(10),
    classes_id VARCHAR(10),
    semester VARCHAR(10),
    year VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (professor_id, course_id, semester, year)
);

ALTER TABLE taking ADD CONSTRAINT consTAKE3 FOREIGN KEY(classes_id) REFERENCES classes(classes_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE taking ADD CONSTRAINT consTAKE4 FOREIGN KEY(semester) REFERENCES classes(semester) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE taking ADD CONSTRAINT consTAKE5 FOREIGN KEY(year) REFERENCES classes(year) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE lectures ADD CONSTRAINT consLEC3 FOREIGN KEY(classes_id) REFERENCES classes(classes_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE lectures ADD CONSTRAINT consLEC4 FOREIGN KEY(semester) REFERENCES classes(semester) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE lectures ADD CONSTRAINT consLEC5 FOREIGN KEY(year) REFERENCES classes(year) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**The Error would be as follows:**

```
ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'consTAKE3' in the referenced table 'classes'
ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'consTAKE4' in the referenced table 'classes'
ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'consTAKE5' in the referenced table 'classes'
ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'consLEC3' in the referenced table 'classes'
ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'consLEC4' in the referenced table 'classes'
ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'consLEC5' in the referenced table 'classes'
```

Right now, I'm trying to execute this from the `cmd` using `ysql –u root –p`. Still, the same problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a composite primary key in all tables, so all references must also include all the composite key columns in the table to map properly.

Unless you have a unique constraint/index on the composite primary key columns on each table.

To create relation in the tables, try this for `dbo.taking`, follow the similar approach for other tables too

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.taking 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_taking_classes
  FOREIGN KEY(course_id, classes_id, semester, year) REFERENCES classes(course_id, 
classes_id, semester, year)
```

Comment: The character length of `course_id` in both the table differ, which results in not creating FK . Please set it to varchar(8) in `taking` table same of `classes`. It will definitely solve the problem. I have created the tables and also have FKs by using the provided query.

Answer (score -1):

The character length of `course_id` in both the table differ, which results in not creating FK . Please set it to `varchar(8)` in `taking` table same of `classes`. It will definitely solve the problem. I have created the tables and also have FKs by using the provided query.

Then follow the above mentioned Query:

> Since you have a composite primary key in all tables, so all
> references must also include all the composite key columns in the
> table to map properly.
>
> Unless you have a unique constraint/index on the composite primary key
> columns on each table.
>
> To create relation in the tables, try this for `dbo.taking`, follow
> the similar approach for other tables too
>
> ```
>   ALTER TABLE dbo.taking 
>   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_taking_classes
>   FOREIGN KEY(course_id, classes_id, semester, year) REFERENCES classes(course_id, 
>   classes_id, semester, year)
> ```

Comment: Nope, this is not correct. Length difference in varchars is allowed in case of foreign keys. The error message was also quite explicit about missing index.